# how to give two different colors to two different text on a button

Tags: css

in the following JSFiddle how can make The text"production "color blue and its value down there,green,for example!

html

```
<button id="btnProduct" type="button" class="Btns" >
```

css

```
.Btns {
        width:200px;              
        height:75px;
        background-color:lightblue;
        color:black;
        font-weight:bold;

    }
```

javascript

```
$("#btnProduct").html('Production:</br></br>'+55);
```

[The Example](https://jsfiddle.net/48mah2jx/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use two `<span>` or `<p>` for both the text having different class name and add respective color for that class in CSS

```
$("#btnProduct").html('<span class="red">Production:</span></br></br><span class="blue">55</span>');
```

and in CSS add styles for `.red` and `.blue`

Answer (score 0):

You could use spans and give them differents styles. 
Change the markup to:

```
$("#btnProduct").html('Production:</br></br>'+<span>55</span>);
```

then in the css:

```
Btn {
 color: black;
}
Btn > span {
 color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>` tags like Rajan said. But if you don't want to compromise the integer, or allow it to change dynamically you can give a specific id to the second span like so:

```
<button id="btnProduct" type="button" class="Btns" >
```

```
$("#btnProduct").html('<span id="green">Production:</span><span id="blue" class="myInt">'+55+'</span>');
```

And the CSS

```
.Btns {
        width:200px;              
        height:75px;
        background-color:lightblue;
        color:black;
        font-weight:bold;

    }
#green {
 color:green;
}
#blue {
  color:blue;
}
```

The Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ps8L9pve/